# Problem with publishing an XNA game

Tags: xna, c#

I can't publish a game in XNA, if I try there comes out 2 errors:

1)Could not find required file 'setup.bin' in'C:\Users\Trica\Desktop\example\example\
example\Engine'.

2)Cannot publish because a project failed to build.

What can I do?

Comment: You're not giving anyone much to go on. What platform? What publishing process? Where and how did you get the errors?

Comment: What platform?? XNA functions ONLY on Windows. Normal publishing process (Project-publish). And there is not the  code that doesn't function. The errors are only those I wrote above.I get the errors only when I try to publish. I don't get errors if I try to publish it on others computers.

Comment: I use Windows  Vista anyway.. may this be the cause it doesn't function?

Comment: XNA "functions" on Windows, Xbox 360, and Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this issue is probably related with bad paths and not with XNA itself.
Take a look at this answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139538/could-not-find-required-file-setup-bin